# Scaling a Covariance Matrix by a factor?

Tags: covariance, matrix-decomposition

I have a $n\times n$ covariance matrix representing the covariance between n random processes. I want to increase all of the covariances by a certain factor, say $1.5x$. Multiplying each covariance value in matrix by $1.5$ yields an invalid covariance matrix when I try to compute the Cholesky decompostion of the matrix.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Valid covariance matrices are symmetric positive semi-definite (SPSD). Multiplying by a scalar factor shouldn't change anything.*

A covariance matrix can be factored as $\Sigma=\tau\Omega\tau,$ where $\tau$ is a diagonal matrix of standard deviations, and $\Omega$ is the correlation matrix. Denote the (positive) rescaling factor as $\lambda,$ we wish to compute $\lambda\Sigma$. This is the same as rescaling the matrix $\tau$ by a factor of $\sqrt{\lambda}$, i.e. computing the product $\lambda\Sigma=\sqrt {\lambda} \tau\Omega(\tau \sqrt {\lambda})$. If we accept that $\Sigma=\tau\Omega\tau$ is SPSD, clearly this rescaling must also be SPSD, since we are only rescaling the standard deviations, which may change independently of correlations.

Per whubr's suggestion, I'll include a simpler demonstration. The definition of PSD is that for a vector $a$, it holds that $a^T\Sigma a\ge0.$ Applying scaling, we can write $a^T\lambda\Sigma a\ge0,$ and rearrange to have $\lambda a \Sigma a\ge0.$ Even under positive scaling $\lambda$, the PSD property is retained. Surely the resulting *product* $a^T\lambda\Sigma a$ will differ, but all we care about is whether we satisfy the inequality.

*I think the problem is numerical, or user error.*
Things to check:

- Is $\Sigma$ symmetric? Some Cholesky factorization routines check for
  symmetry; small, nonzero differences between $\Sigma_{ij}$ and $\Sigma_{ji}$ can occasionally creep into $\Sigma$, and cause these checks to fail. Two cheap fixes are to average $\Sigma_{ij}$ and $\Sigma_{ji}$, or just set $\Sigma_{ij}$ = $\Sigma_{ji}$.
- Is $\Sigma$ PSD? If $\Sigma$ isn't PSD, there's no reason to believe $\lambda\Sigma$ is. Look at the eigenvalue decomposition $\Sigma=Q\Lambda Q^T.$ If you have some slightly negative eigenvalues, this can be the culprit (again, because of accumulated error). One quick fix is to do the following: set each $\Lambda_{ii}=\max(\Lambda_{ii}, \epsilon\times\max(\Lambda))$ for some small $\epsilon$ such as $\epsilon=10^{-6}.$ (That is, you're fixing the value of the smallest eigenvalue to be at least $\epsilon$ times the size of the largest eigenvalue.) Then recompute the factorization using the modified diagonal matrix of eigenvalues: $\tilde{\Sigma}=Q\tilde{\Lambda}Q^T.$

Since we're talking about factorizations of covariance matrices, it's worth noting that the Cholesky factorization $\Sigma=LL^T$ can be related to the correlation-standard deviation factorization. Denote the Cholesky factor of $\Omega$ as $A$, so we have $\Omega=AA^T$. Now we can write $\Sigma=\tau AA^T \tau$, which implies $L=\tau A$.

Comment: +1. A simpler argument relies on the definition of positive-definiteness: the quadratic form represented by the matrix is non-negative (and equal to zero only when applied to the zero vector).  Rescaling the matrix rescales the form by the same amount, making it obvious that no amount of positive rescaling will change the positive-definite property (nor will it destroy the symmetry of the matrix).

Comment: @whuber Thank you. Your point is well-taken.

Comment: I had actually a similar problem (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162016/covariance-function-with-circular-similarity-property) while creating model covariance matrices, very small negative eigenvalues can mess up the positive definiteness.

Comment: @user777 So in order to scale correctly, one needs to (1) ensure that the matrix is symmetric and PSD, (2) do Cholesky decomposition to get L, (3) scale the diagonal of $L$ and $L^T$ with some $\lambda$, (4) get the new covariance matrix $\tilde{\Sigma}=\tilde{L} \tilde{L}^T$ ?

Comment: @xeon Computing $\lambda\Sigma$ directly should scale the matrix correctly, provided that $\Sigma$ is SPSD. I was merely pointing out that there are a couple of potential pitfalls that could be causing OP some problems.